# std::map with struct as key not working as expected

Tags: c++, struct, stdmap

I have two maps to store a list of User objects as values.  The keys for those values are a uint32_t and a SocketAddress struct as defined below.

The first map inserts values just fine but looking at the locals while debugging, I can see that the second doesn't seem to insert values at all.  Here's the relevant code:

SocketAddress:

```
struct SocketAddress {
    sockaddr from;
    socklen_t fromlen;
    SocketAddress& operator=(const SocketAddress &source);
    bool operator==(const SocketAddress &source) const;
    bool operator!=(const SocketAddress &source) const;
    bool operator<(const SocketAddress &source) const;
    bool operator>(const SocketAddress &source) const;
    bool operator<=(const SocketAddress &source) const;
    bool operator>=(const SocketAddress &source) const;
};

Socket::SocketAddress& Socket::SocketAddress::operator=(const SocketAddress &source) {
    memcpy(&from, &source.from, source.fromlen);
    fromlen = source.fromlen;
    return *this;
}

bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator==(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return (fromlen == source.fromlen && memcmp(&from, &source.from, fromlen) == 0);
}
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator!=(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return !this->operator==(source);
}
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator<(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return (fromlen < source.fromlen || memcmp(&from, &source.from, fromlen) < 0);
}
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator>(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return (fromlen > source.fromlen || memcmp(&from, &source.from, source.fromlen) > 0);
}
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator<=(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return !this->operator>(source);
}
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator>=(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return !this->operator<(source);
}
```

User Constructor and associated variables:

```
std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<User>> User::_usersListBySession;
std::map<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>> User::_userListByAddress;
std::atomic<unsigned int> User::_nextSessionID = 0;

User::User(const Socket::SocketAddress& addr) {
    address = addr;

    sessionID = ++_nextSessionID;

            // This seems to work just fine
    _usersListBySession.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<User>>(sessionID, std::shared_ptr<User>(this)));
            // This does not
    _userListByAddress.insert(std::pair<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>>(addr, std::shared_ptr<User>(this)));
}
```

Definition of address:

```
    const Socket::SocketAddress& address
```

Segment of code that doesn't operate as intended.

```
    std::shared_ptr<User> user = User::getUserWithAddress(address);
    if (!user) {
        user = std::shared_ptr<User>(new User(address));
    }
```

Map search functions:

```
std::shared_ptr<User> User::getUserWithAddress(const Socket::SocketAddress& addr) {
    return _userListByAddress[addr];
}

std::shared_ptr<User> User::getUserWithSessionID(uint32_t sessionid) {
    return _usersListBySession[sessionid];
}
```

When making the call to User::getUserWithAddress(address), the user returned has no user!  Looking at the pair in memory, it looks like the address is stored as a key, but no pointer to the user is stored.  I'm not sure what to think!  Anyone have any ideas?

---

Edit:
It looks like there were a few problems identified by the users below though it doesn't look like that was the cause of my problems.

After fixing the operators, I've isolated the issue down to these lines:

```
assert(this->address == addr);
_userListByAddress.insert(std::pair<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>>(addr, std::shared_ptr<User>(this)));
assert(this->address == addr);
```

The first assertion passes, the second fails.

---

Edit #2:

Looks like I've solved the issue by doing this:

```
std::shared_ptr<User> user(this);
_usersListBySession.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<User>>(sessionID, user));
assert(this->address == addr); // works
_userListByAddress.insert(std::pair<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>>(addr, user));
assert(this->address == addr); // works
```

I have no idea why.  Sounds like a job for another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implementation is not correct:

```
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator<(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return (fromlen < source.fromlen || memcmp(&from, &source.from, fromlen) < 0);
}
```

One possible correct way is:

```
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator<(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    if (fromlen < source.fromlen) return true;
    else if (fromlen > source.fromlen) return false;
    //else: fromlen == source.fromlen
    return (memcmp(&from, &source.from, fromlen) < 0);
}
```

Your implementation is not correct because it does not imply strong ordering, you can easily find two `SockedAddr` objects `a, b` which are at the same time: `a < b` and `b < a`...

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator<` is wrong.  You should only compare.contents if the lengths are equal to maintain strict weak ordering.  As written you could have two instances of the class with both A

Use the `if a not equal b return a less than b` pattern to write brain dead operator <.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of operator `<` may be comparing address components beyond the length:

```
bool Socket::SocketAddress::operator<(const SocketAddress &source) const {
    return (fromlen < source.fromlen || memcmp(&from, &source.from, fromlen) < 0);
}
```

Since `||` short-circuits the evaluation, the call of `memcmp` will be made only when `fromlen < source.fromlen` evaluates to `false`, meaning that `fromlen >= source.fromlen`.

As the result, the call of `memcmp` will pass the *larger* of the two lengths, meaning that when the prefixes of both addresses up to `source.fromlen` match, `memcmp` will compare bytes beyond the valid portion of the address.

To fix this, you should pass `source.fromlen` to `memcmp` instead of `fromlen`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a problem I thought I fixed.  I guess the || operator does throw a wrench into that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've solved the issue by doing this (in addition to the other helpful comments above):

```
std::shared_ptr<User> user(this);
_usersListBySession.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<User>>(sessionID, user));
assert(this->address == addr); // previously works, still works
_userListByAddress.insert(std::pair<Socket::SocketAddress, std::shared_ptr<User>>(addr, user));
assert(this->address == addr); // previously fails, now works
```